# Where is my gcloud database

Tags: mysql, automated-install, gcloud

This'll be a settling in problem: I've created a wordpress site using gcloud's installer. I can see my files but not my database. I expected the database to be sitting in https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances but it's not there.

Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 1):

If you have deployed WordPress using [Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/) your MySQL database is installed on the VM and not Google CloudSQL. To access the MySQL database installed on the WordPress VM you can use PHPMyAdmin interface i.e http://VM-EXTERNAL-IP/phpmyadmin.

You can migrate your database from GCE VM to CloudSQL if you want. For more information you can visit [CloudSQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/).